# Using Reflection to use a namespace on certain OSs

Tags: c#, .net, reflection

I'm creating a program that uses the CodeProject CoreAudioApi (pretty popular framework for manipulating audio), but the problem is the CoreAudioApi uses system calls that aren't available in any versions of Windows earlier than Vista.  If I run a program with CoreAudioApi compiled with it (using a `using` statement as normal), the program will crash on anything earlier than Vista.

I've created this function to get the version number of the current environment:

```
win_version = Environment.OSVersion.Version.Major;
```

That returns the major version number I need.  '6' is Vista/7, anything else is not, which is all I need to determine.  Utilizing this, I need to determine whether or not to include the CoreAudioApi namespace if the OS is over or equal to '6'.  From research, `using`s need to be compiled with the program, but I've also read about something called Reflection - which might be what I need.

Once I get the CoreAudioApi namespace `using`'d (sorry for the lack of terminology), the rest is easy.  How can I do this?

**TL;DR**
I need some form of code that would effectively do this:

```
using System;
using System.Text;
//etc
if(currentWindowsVersion>=6) using CoreAudioApi;
```

Except control structures won't work outside of a class, and all namespaces are compiled with the program, not controlled individually.

Thanks!

---

**EDIT:** So far, I'm using this to load the CoreAudioApi namespace as a compiled assembly:

```
if(win_version>=6){
    CoreAudioApi = Assembly.LoadFrom("CoreAudio.dll");
    CoreAudioApi.GetLoadedModules();
    CoreAudioApi.GetTypes();
    MessageBox.Show("Loaded CoreAudioApi");
}
```

From here, what I need to do is actually use the types, and methods from the API.  My code that works on Windows Vista/7 is this:

```
public static MMDeviceEnumerator devEnum;
public static MMDevice defaultDevice;
//later in a mute method:
defaultDevice.AudioEndpointVolume.Mute = true/false;
```

I don't even really need devEnum AFAIK, so really the only important lines are the last two (besides the comment).

Comment: You can't use `using` this way, you need to dynamically load your assembly, have a look at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xbe1wdx9.aspx
Specifically, the `LoadFrom(string path)` method and its alternatives.

Comment: Slightly off topic, but it's much simpler to grab the major version number with `Environment.OSVersion.Version.Major`.

Comment: @SteveDanner That is much handier, thanks!

Comment: How is this supposed to work? What does your code do when that API isn't available?

Comment: Generally speaking, what are you going to do if the major version is less than 6?

Comment: @SteveDanner and Rawling I'm going to use the Windows XP code I have (waveOutSetVolume for system, not app) that already works perfectly on Windows XP and lower.  waveOutSetVolume doesn't adjust the System volume on Windows Vista/7, only the actual application it's called from.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've just tried the following:

- Create a new console application project
- Add the `CoreAudioApi` project from CodeProject to the solution
- Add a project reference to `CoreAudioApi` in my console app
- Create the following classes:

```
interface IAudio { void SetVolume(float level); }

class XpAudio : IAudio {
    public void SetVolume(float level) {
        // I do nothing, but this is where your old-style code would go
    }
}

class VistaAudio : IAudio {
    public void SetVolume(float level) {
        MMDeviceEnumerator devEnum = new MMDeviceEnumerator();
        MMDevice defaultDevice = devEnum
            .GetDefaultAudioEndpoint(EDataFlow.eRender, ERole.eMultimedia);
        defaultDevice.AudioEndpointVolume.MasterVolumeLevel = level;
    }
}

class Program {
    static void Main(string[] args) {
        IAudio setter = Environment.OSVersion.Version.Major >= 6
            ? (IAudio)new VistaAudio()
            : (IAudio)new XpAudio();
        float val = float.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        setter.SetVolume(val);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

This *runs* on both my server (~ Windows 7) and local (Windows XP) machines. On my XP machine it'll happily take in a value and ignore it; on my server, it throws an exception, (presumably because I don't have a sound output). If I make my XP machine run the `CoreAudioApi`, I get an exception *when I input a value*, not before.

The question is, what are you doing *differently* to make your application break? Are you using `CoreAudioApi` code at startup?

EDIT: After seeing your edit, if you do this, you shouldn't need to mess about with `Assembly.LoadFrom` at all. The framework should *dynamically* load that assembly if (and only if) and when it needs to.

Comment: It seems to be working, but:
1) How do I set the volume like this?  Never used interfaces before
2) If the CoreAudioApi is even used at all on Windows XP, it crashes, no matter if it uses it or not.

Comment: @Jaxo I assume then your program crashes as soon as it runs, rather than as soon as it tries to set the volume? In which case, I've got no idea what I'm talknig about, and this answer is rubbish :)

Comment: Naw, I couldn't figure this stuff out.  I tried compiling a .dll and loading that as an assembly using Reflection, but it doesn't run the way I had hoped.  Thanks though!

Comment: This is on the right track. If even referencing the CoreAudioApi will crash the app, then I'd suggest deploying two builds. One for Vista and up, one for XP.

Comment: @Jaxo I've tried this, and I can build an app that _references_ the `CoreAudioApi` and runs on XP as long as it doesn't _call_ any of the `CoreAudioApi` code. As far as I can tell you must be using some of the code without checking the OS version first.

Comment: Use this method, but the two implementations (XpVolSetter and VistaVolSetter) in separate assemblies. Then have your factory pull load the proper assembly and return the correct IVolSetter.

Comment: @hometoast It works for me even if they're in the same assembly.

Answer (score -1):

`COREAUDIOAPI.dll` does not work on XP or earlier, because they cant handle `MMDEVICE` API (Device Enumeration). I dont know about Vista.